# target folder not in sync with files in the explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to understand better the maven compilation process in Eclipse and running some simple tests.
For some reason I can't see all the files that are in the "target" folder in the Windows explorer from inside Eclipse Project Explorer (that is even after I refresh using F5).
classes and test-classes can't be seen !

Thanks for the help!

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

[image: Explorer screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Explorer defaults to not showing output folders.

You can change this by clicking on the view menu (the small triangle in the top right corner of the view). Select 'Customize View...' and the deselect 'Java output folders' in the list (checked items in this list are **not** shown so you uncheck things you want to see).